# Turn off Ubuntu phpmyadmin case sensitivity

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

As I was in the process of deploying nodejs app on digital ocean server

One issue I had was that phpmyadmin was case sentitive and I developmed on windows on mysql workbench which didn't had case sensitity...

Im having issue in deploying the database

Please help me.. I've looked up solutions related to this problem but they were out of date and didn't worked for me

Comment: As a general rule to avoid a bunch of issues, you should consider running a MySQL server in linux, since most hostings are linux in the end (because of pricing). Now, you can use a local vm, or local server if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Add to the [mysqld] section:

`lower_case_table_names = 1`

Then restart MySQL

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Probably you'd have to recreate (reimport) all your tables after those changes.

**Update**

If there is no `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, or you can see those lines in it:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Then just edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

You should see the `[mysqld]`section there.

Comment: hi thank you .... i have tried using this but there is no [mysqld] section in  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: That's not a problem, just add that section in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: but now i have another problem .... when i create a table let suppose user ... mysql creates 2 tables one with upper case and the other with lowercase...

Comment: As per documentation: "Use lower_case_table_names=1 on all systems. The main disadvantage with this is that when you use SHOW TABLES or SHOW DATABASES, you do not see the names in their original lettercase. " So probably when you create table via Windows Workbench with default lower_case_table_names=0 vlue, it creates table with upper case, and then MySQL on Linux converts them to lowercase. Not sure but you can try.

Comment: Probably you'd have to recreate (reimport) all your database and tables after those changes to take effect.

Comment: Before changing this setting, do a complete dump of all databases, and drop all databases. You won't be able to drop them after setting lower_case_table_names to 1, because any uppercase characters in database or table names will prevent them from being referenced.

Then set lower_case_table_names to 1, restart MySQL, and re-load your data, which will convert everything to lowercase, including any subsequent queries made.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpROa.png)

i have open the file 
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
using sudo editor but there is no section which says [mysqld] i have tried adding it my self but the database then dont work properly